# How to get values of select menu?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get values (all regions) of select menu on [this webpage](https://www.yemeksepeti.com/en/istanbul). What's my fault? Almost tried all combinations but result is zero. One of them is:

```
  page <- read_html("https://www.yemeksepeti.com/en/istanbul")
  regions <- page %>% 
    html_nodes("div") %>% 
    html_nodes("span") %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="select2-ys-areaSelector-container"]') %>% 
    html_attr("title")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried  '//*[@id="ys-areaSelector"]' ?

Comment: Not zero but NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is kind of a ugly beast. Get the id of the `select` element then get all options groups and finally get their text data. Use `html_text` to convert it to R `character`.

```
page <- read_html("https://www.yemeksepeti.com/en/istanbul")
regions <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="ys-areaSelector"]/optgroup/*/text()') %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a css selector combination assuming all option values wanted

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://www.yemeksepeti.com/en/istanbul")
options <- page %>% 
  html_nodes('#ys-areaSelector [data-url]') %>%
  html_text()
```